# HTML elements inside <script/> getting automatically commented

Tags: html, jsf, browser, xhtml

I have an xhtml page with following:

```
<script type="text/html" id="test1">
    <li>
        test
    </li>
</script>
```

However when the page is loaded in browser(testing in Google Chrome) I see it as following:

```
<script type="text/html" id="test1"><!--    

        <li>test

//--></li>

    <!--   

        <li>test

//--></script>
```

Why this is happening & how to prevent this ? This doesn't happen if page is `html` instead of `xhtml`.

--

Comment: This is normally done as a type of "template".  If the script tag has a type other than `text/javascript`, then it won't be ran as a script.

Comment: yes  I need to create a template for converting JSON data to HTML client side using [John Resig's mircotemplating engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating).

Answer (score 1):

XHTML is #PCDATA while HTML is CDATA.  In order to keep that code from being parsed, you have to wrap it in CDATA tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
<li>
    test
</li>

//]]></script>
```

Even if that works though, I'm not sure why you'd want to have HTML inside script tag, it's invalid code and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: because I need to create a template for converting JSON data to HTML client side using [John Resig's mircotemplating engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating).

Comment: I tried using `<![CDATA[` & `]]>` but that leaves me with another problem that since I'm using the content inside `<script/>` tag as template for pushing new HTML to document, CDATA is also included in the template, so is there any alternate for this ?

Comment: What about something like [JSON 2 HTML](http://json2html.com/)? That will convert your JSON to HTML client side using jQuery.

Comment: I have no other issues using resig's small script that force me to use another library. A workaround for this issue may be to use a hidden span instead of script tag.... are there yet any reasons to consider migrating to a new library??